# webkit.net error "Cookies not enabled in browser"

Tags: c#, cookies, browser-cache, webkit.net

Hi I am developing an application using [Webkit.net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) . It was working fine until yesterday facebook and gmail are facing problem with cookies. I can login to gmail but i cann't signin facebook, also tried to login with WebKitBrowserTest.exe provied by webkit.net binaries.  See the screenshots of gmail and facebook below. 
[image]

 
 
and after login in gmail when i click any email this error occurs in top of window

[image]

 
 
How do i enabled cookies. when i visit [whatismybrowser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled) its saying cookies are enabled.

Comment: please someone help still got the same issue